# How to set global locale?

Tags: qt, qml, locale, qtquick2

I'm writing a simple calculator. Comma is the decimal separator in my default locale. I'd like to globally (for all `TextField`s) set the decimal separator to be the point `.` instead of the comma `,` so that I can input points in a `TextField`.

How can I achieve this?

```
TextField {
    validator: DoubleValidator {
        bottom: 0.0
        decimals: 1
        notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation
    }
    placeholderText: "0.0"
}
```

Comment: Try to call `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::c());` in C++ code at startup.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, can you create an answer so that it can be marked as accepted?

Comment: **NEVER** insert the solution *inside* the question. Either provide it as an answer to your own question or ask the person that suggested the solution to provide an answer. @PavelStrakhov please provide the answer so that it can be correctly marked as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::c());` in C++ code at startup.